# How can I discourage (but not prevent!) the browser from word-wrapping text in an element?

Tags: css

I'd like to discourage the browser from word-wrapping text in an inline element unless it's necessary.

Suppose I have a `<code>` tag:

1. If the tag's contents fit in one line, I want the browser to display the element all on a single line. I.e., the browser should wrap text either before or after the element and never inside the element.
2. If the tag's contents cannot fit on a single line, I want the browser to wrap the text in the `<code>` tag.

Things I've tried:

1. `white-space: nowrap`. This only achieves #1.
2. `overflow-wrap: break-word`. This only achieves #2.
3. Combining `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow-wrap: break-word`: Looks like the `white-space` property has precedence: this only achieves #1.
4. `display: inline-block`. This achieves both! However, it introduces a host of other display issues that are not worth the complexity to compensate for.

Comment: I was ready to answer `display:inline-block` (which is what I use on one of my own websites to achieve exactly this) until I came to your point #4. What are the issues you are facing?

Comment: Lists are a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/w2em1zca/  If the codeblock spans multiple lines, it then drops below the bullet. You may need to narrow the rendered HTML pane to see this.

Comment: `vertical-align: top;` solves that.